Emoji Encoding Issues in Maven Test Output on Windows PowerShell (VSCode/IntelliJ)
I am having Problems with Emojis in a Maven project in conjunction with the PowerShell.
A minimalistic repository for reproduction can be found here:
https://github.com/tippfelher/reproduce-mvn-junit-encoding/tree/main
Problem:
Running mvn test or ./mvnw test in the VSCode or IntelliJ IDE on Windows breaks the Emojis in the output (I even tried ./mvnw test -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8):

I works fine though when running through a Run configuration or inside a Dev Container:


Question:
How to fix the PS output?

I quess this has something to do with Displaying Unicode in PowerShell, try to set: $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding =                     New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding  first.

This is working (+1) Is there a way to set this from the mvn command? I don't want to tell developers to manually configure their terminal window every time they want to execute  a test..

Or have configuration file in the project root that PS automatically grabs to configure itself.

You might consider to deploy a  PowerShell $Profile, see: about profiles
